# Was the KJV "too highly colored in many places with the party ideas and opinions of those who made it"?

Tags: church-history, bible-translation, kjv

In the [Emphatic Diaglott](https://studybible.info/version/Diaglott), the second paragraph under the heading "To the Reader" states:

> But can it be fairly said that such is the case with our present English Version? We opine not. Though freely acknowledging that it is sufficiently plain to teach men the social and religious duties of life, and the path to Immortality, yet it is a notable fact that King James' Translation is far from being a faithful reflection of the mind of the Spirit, as contained in the Original Greek in which the books of the New Testament were written. There are some thousands of words which are either mistranslated, or too obscurely rendered; besides others which are now obsolete, through improvement in the language. **Besides this, it has been too highly colored in many places with the party ideas and opinions of those who made it, to be worthy of full and implicit confidence being placed in it as a genuine record.** In the words of Dr. Macknight, "it was made a little too complaisant to the King, in favoring his notions of predestination, election, witchcraft, familiar spirits, and kingly rights, and these it is probable were also the translators' opinions. That their translation is partial, speaking the language of, and giving authority to one sect." And according to Dr. Gell, it was wrested and partial, "and only adapted to one sect;" but he imputes this, not to the translators, but to those who employed them, for even some of the translators complained that they could not follow their own judgment in the matter, but were restrained by "reasons of state." [bold mine]

Is there any historical record as to the veracity of this statement about the wording of the King James Version?

Comment: I do remember hearing that compared to the Geneva Bible the two translations differed on how to translation "church" and "bishop" for political reasons, but don't know the details.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable. Opinions are going to be extremely different and there is no way of objectively measuring it.

Comment: @DJClayworth This is not a question of opinion, but if there is anything recorded about the statement made in the Emphatic Diaglott.

Comment: I think this question is easily answerable if there are quotes from church authorities saying things like "you must replace congregation with church in the translation".

Comment: @agarza If you think there are more substantial statements in your source than this one, then perhaps you should include them. Otherwise, you are asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: @agarza The Emphatic Diaglott is one person's work. If you are looking for additional information from that person about his statements, just check his writings. But it is certain that other Christians hold other opinions about any bias in the KJV, and so the veracity of  the statement is certainly a matter of opinion.

Comment: “William Tyndale, born in 1494, martyred in 1536, has a good claim to be both the founder of the King James Bible and the father of the English language... His translation of the New Testament came out in 1525.  It was the first printed Bible in English.” Source: Chapter 2 ‘The Book of Books – the radical impact of the King James Bible 1611-2011’ by Melvyn Bragg, Historian: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melvyn_Bragg

Answer (score 3):

It has been calculated by some that 83% of the New Testament part of the  Authorised Version (see [Wikipedia - William Tyndale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Tyndale) footnotes 9 & 10) is fully attributable to William Tyndale. If that be true (and from my own studies I do not doubt it) then any comment about the AV being biased in any way has to distinguish between any supposed bias in Tyndale separately from any supposed bias in the AV translators.

Scrivener's learned Greek Text of 1894 has shown what texts (Erasmus, Beza, Stephanus and Computensian Polyglot) were used in which places by the AV translators and so that, also, would need to be examined with regard to any supposed 'bias' regarding the choice of source.

It is noticeable that the AV translators favoured Beza, in one important place,  by adding his words εκ σου 'of thee' to the words of Luke in 1:35 turning 'which shall be begotten, shall be called Son of God' into 'which shall be begotten **of thee**, shall be called Son of God' : a very noticeable difference with serious implications.

And it is certainly true that one can discern places in the AV where the translators favour certain doctrinal views which are later expressed in detail in both the Westminster Confession and the Savoy Declaration.

One example of this is where the AV translators mis-translate Romans 5:18 δι ενος δικαιωματος as 'by the righteousness of one' (mis-representing a prepositional genitive as a possessive and adding an article not present in the original). Were they correct, then the concomitant expression δι ενος ανθρωπου in Romans 5:12 should be translated 'by the man of one' which is clearly ridiculous.

(See the Englishman's Greek New Testament *Literal Interlinear Translation* and Green's *Literal Translation* which have the correct reading.)

'By one man' and 'by one righteousness' is the correct translation. But the mis-translation which would have a schoolboy rightly castigated in Greek class is clearly an interpretation which favours the doctrine of Dr John Owen who influenced the Savoy Declaration of 1658 which contains support for the concept of 'active and passive obedience'.

However the quotation cited by the OP above, and the entire text in the link provided, bears *not one single reference to the  AV* and therefore (either from just that quotation, or from the entire article) no evidence whatsoever is offered of any bias at all, only a statement of unsubstantiated opinion.

The writer goes on to mention Vatican manuscript 1209 which is the Codex Vaticanus so it becomes obvious that the argument is not really against the AV, or rather Tyndale, or even the matter of English translation at all, *the argument is against the Greek Received Text, as such.*

Thus the above comments are singularly insufficient to persuade myself to leave the most commonly available English translation of the *Textus Receptus*, the Greek 'Received Text', in favour of what is being argued for, namely the Greek Text of 1881 and thereafter, which leans heavily on the Codex Sinaiticus and the Codex Vaticanus, which disagree between themselves in 3,000 places *in just the four gospel accounts* of Matthew, Mark, Luke and John, as publicised by Dean John Burgon in his book 'Revision Revised' 1881.

Comment: With all due respect, " δι ενος δικαιωματος" does mean "by one's righteousness..." and "δι ενος ανθρωπου" does mean "through one man's..." Also, εκ σου adds nothing semantically in Luke 1:25 since the one born and the one he's born of are both explicit in the text: Jesus and Mary. So for Jesus to be 'born,' and to be 'born of,' does not mean two different things, if we know who the mother is - and we do.

Comment: @SolaGratia I disagree. The genitive case is there because of the preposition (δια which becomes δι by apocopic elision) . You are suggesting a genitive of possession which is not supported by the text. (See Daniel B Wallace _Beyond the Basics_ pp 72-136, the genitive case, and pp 355-389 prepositions and the cases they govern).

Comment: (I meant "by one man" for δι ενος ανθρωπου not "by one man's.") The genitive can serve double duty: it depends on whether you take the genitive as adjectival in the first word, or as nominal. The context makes it clear which is meant. Here, it's clear that "by the righteousness/righteous act of one" correlates and is opposite to "by the offense of one."

Comment: @SolaGratia As they say in the House of Commons, I refer the honourable member to the answer (and the reference) I gave earlier. The Englishman's Greek New Testament _Interlinear Translation_ agrees with myself, not with yourself.

Comment: @SolaGratia Regarding the Beza intrusion, γενναο  is begotten (not 'born'). It is τίκτο 'delivered' that refers to the act of birth. It is important not to confuse begetting with the delivery of a child. Both Jesus' words and Luke's/Matthew's narratives are very particular as to the choice of which word to use.

Comment: But Jesus was both begotten and born of Mary, since anyone born of someone was begotten by them also of necessity. I know gennao means begotten but it can be rendered born too, since they are synonyms and born is a more modern way of speaking. There is no difference between begotten and begotten of Mary, since Jesus was both.

Comment: @SolaGratia says "*anyone born of someone was begotten by them also of necessity*". Not necessarily. Surrogate mothers bear children without having begotten them. But I suspect that wasn't a known possibility until recent times.

Comment: Can you expand "*a very noticeable difference with serious implications*" to make it more obvious what those implications are?

Comment: @RayButterworth The wording of the original is very, very precise in Matthew and Luke. There was a begetting within Mary _prior_ to delivery. That is _not_ the case with John the Baptist's birth where begetting is a _result_ of delivery. The implications are both important and wonderful.

Comment: Obviously Jesus was begotten of Mary if He is the "of the seed of David according to the flesh," and is the "son of David." Come on now.

Comment: Besides, Gabriel said Mary would conceive Jesus. It uses the standard language for conceive.

Comment: @SolaGratia I refer you, again, to the wording of the apostolic documents regarding _gennao_ and _tikto_. And there I must leave it. No further comment.